# MKTime Function Returning Wrong Time?

Tags: php, datetime, mktime

I'm having a bit of trouble with the mktime function. On my production server, if I execute the following:

```
echo '<p>' . mktime(24, 0,0, 8,29,2009) . ' - 12pm</p>';
echo '<p>' . mktime(23, 0,0, 8,29,2009) . ' - 11pm</p>';
echo '<p>' . mktime(22, 0,0, 8,29,2009) . ' - 10pm</p>';
```

And then convert those timestamps back to readable format (using [www.unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com) for quick conversion), the times are all off by one hour. I originally thought this was a problem with 2400 VS 0000, but that wouldn't account for the other dates being off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server has a different time zone than you are expecting. Unix timestamps are measured in seconds since 1.1.1970 00:00:00 **GMT**, so you have a hidden time zone conversion in your code. You can either

- use [`gmmktime()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) to create a timestamp for a GMT date,
- use the builtin [DateTime class](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php),
- correct the [timezone settings in php.ini](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone), or
- set the time zone to use with the function [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: I set my default time zone, which wasn't set. Further investigation looks like I jumped the gun, the timestamp converts forwards and backwards just fine, and it makes it into the DB just fine. It seems to be a display issue only. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following from the command line and got the following (expected) output.  What happens if you run them?

```
$ php -r "echo date('H:i:s Y-m-d', mktime(24, 0, 0, 8, 29, 2009));"
00:00:00 2009-08-30

$ php -r "echo date('H:i:s Y-m-d', mktime(23, 0, 0, 8, 29, 2009));"
23:00:00 2009-08-29

$ php -r "echo date('H:i:s Y-m-d', mktime(22, 0, 0, 8, 29, 2009));"
22:00:00 2009-08-29
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in `mktime` I input the day and month with **leading zeros**. Than the function returned me wrong results. One option would be to remove the leading zero with a function like

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```

Source: [How to remove all leading zeroes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098688/php-string-remove-all-leading-zeroes)

or

```
$var = (int)$var;
```

Source: [PHP remove first zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563740/php-remove-first-zeros)

I used one possibility from soulmerge:

```
$date = new DateTime($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute . ':' . $seconds);
$match_time = $date->getTimestamp();
```

But the timezone should be always set (either with [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or directly with [`DateTime`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

Comment: Whilst not the culprit in the OP, worth while to note this as a possible pit fall.