# How to remove all leading zeroes in a string

Tags: php, string

If I have a string

```
00020300504
00000234892839
000239074
```

how can I get rid of the leading zeroes so that I will only have this

```
20300504
234892839
239074
```

note that the number above was generated randomly.

Comment: Are these three separate strings, or one string with newlines separating each number? I noticed when editing your question that you had `<br>` tags separating the numbers; are they actually part of your string?

Answer (score 522, accepted):

[`ltrim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```

Comment: Caveat $str := '0'. Addressed in my answer, based on this answer.

Comment: why overcomplicate things? and mike it's $str += 0; as explained here: https://nabtron.com/kiss-code/

Comment: @NabeelKhan That would not answer the question, which does *not* ask to convert the string to an integer. See the comments on Svisstack's answer for why this is not such a great solution.

Comment: @lonesomeday you should read his question carefully where he mentions: "note that the number above was generated randomly." so they're integers already :)

Comment: Caution: This will turn '0' into ''

Comment: @Goose Well that is a leading zero!

Comment: @Goose well, that's why it's called ltrim()!

Answer (score 15):

```
(string)((int)"00000234892839")
```

Comment: I just tried an `(int) "00009384783473"` (random number) and my result was 2147483647. If I cast it as a float however, it seems to work ok. Strange

Comment: manual says that "The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed)"

Comment: Not strange.  Integers in php go up to 2^31, which is 2147483647.  For any larger numbers, you'll have to use lonesomeday's string-based solution.

Comment: Casting to float might appear to work, but at some point you'll get roundoff errors.

Comment: how about the idea of evaluating each of the string by using a loop statement, that when it gets to a non zero digit(or string), it will get the index of that digit and drop all the preceding zero's then echo the string which starts with the first non zero value..

Comment: I wouldn't pull in conversions and float arithmetic for a simple string problem. lonesomeday's solution will be much faster - in my testing about 60 - 70 % faster than (string)(float) casting.

Answer (score 12):

you can add "+" in your variable,

example :

```
$numString = "0000001123000";
echo +$numString;
```

Answer (score 10):

Similar to another suggestion, except will not obliterate actual zero:

```
if (ltrim($str, '0') != '') {
    $str = ltrim($str, '0');
} else {
    $str = '0';
}
```

Or as was suggested (as of PHP 5.3), shorthand ternary operator can be used:

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0') ?: '0';
```

Comment: `$str = ltrim($str, '0') ?: '0';`   -- no redundant trim call.

Answer (score 10):

Don't know why people are using so complex methods to achieve such a simple thing! And regex? Wow!

Here you go, the easiest and simplest way (as explained here: https://nabtron.com/kiss-code/ ):

```
$a = '000000000000001';
$a += 0;

echo $a; // will output 1
```

Comment: This seems like a simpler solution, but it doesn't handle any size of string like other answers do.  You're converting from a string to an integer and then back as a string - simpler to merely shorten the string.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't know if it's the best solution with the type conversions.

Comment: Please don't do this... this is why PHP gets a bad rep

Comment: Just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should. This code makes no sense on the surface, even though it technically works, and that simply makes your code more difficult for another developer to understand. There's nothing complex about using `ltrim()`, a function with clear meaning that was specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Regex was proposed already, but not correctly:

```
<?php
    $number = '00000004523423400023402340240';
    $withoutLeadingZeroes = preg_replace('/^0+/', '', $number)
    echo $withoutLeadingZeroes;
?>
```

output is then:

```
4523423400023402340240
```

Background on Regex:
the `^` signals beginning of string and the `+` sign signals more or none of the preceding sign. Therefore, the regex `^0+` matches all zeroes at the beginning of a string.

Comment: `preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think preg_replace is the answer..
old thread but just happen to looking for this today. ltrim and (int) casting is the winner.

```
<?php
 $numString = "0000001123000";
 $actualInt = "1123000";

 $fixed_str1 = preg_replace('/000+/','',$numString);
 $fixed_str2 = ltrim($numString, '0');
 $fixed_str3 = (int)$numString;

 echo $numString . " Original";
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $fixed_str1 . " Fix1";
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $fixed_str2 . " Fix2";
 echo "<br>";
 echo $fixed_str3 . " Fix3";
 echo "<br>";
 echo $actualInt . " Actual integer in string";

 //output

 0000001123000 Origina
 1123 Fix1
 1123000 Fix2
 1123000 Fix3
 1123000 Actual integer in tring
```

Comment: If you add the ^ operator at the start of the regex, it is a valid solution though.

Answer (score 0):

A short hack can be to use round() it will remove leading zeros.

```
echo round('00020300504'); //20300504
```

Answer (score -1):

Ajay Kumar offers the simplest *echo +$numString;*
I use these:

```
echo round($val = "0005");
echo $val = 0005;
    //both output 5
echo round($val = 00000648370000075845);
echo round($val = "00000648370000075845");
    //output 648370000075845, no need to care about the other zeroes in the number
    //like with regex or comparative functions. Works w/wo single/double quotes
```

Actually any math function will take the number from the "string" and treat it like so. It's much simpler than any regex or comparative functions.
I saw that in php.net, don't remember where.

Answer (score -1):

Im Fixed with this way.

its very simple. only pass a string its remove zero start of string.

```
$str = ltrim($str,'0');
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want a run-on of three or more zeros to be removed and your example is one string:

```
    $test_str ="0002030050400000234892839000239074";
    $fixed_str = preg_replace('/000+/','',$test_str);
```

You can make the regex pattern fit what you need if my assumptions are off.

This help?

Comment: Incorrect, sorry. This will also cut the '000' from the middle of the string.