# Properly remove leading zeroes with decimals like 0.1

Tags: php

I aim to remove leading zeros like this:

```
echo ltrim(000.1, '0'); // .1 (should end up as 0.1)
echo ltrim(0, '0'); // empty (should end up as 0)
echo ltrim(00005.5, '0'); // 5.5 (correct)
```

Using `ltrim()` works fine with values like `00005.5` but doesn't work with `0.1` as `0` (as you would expect by the logic).

My question is, how can I remove leading zeros in values like `0.5` and avoid trimming value if it is `0`?

Comment: `echo floatval(000.1);` -> `0.1` (works the same with the other values)

Comment: Your definition of _should_ is curious. Have your the function reference manual?

Comment: If you are dealing with numbers, and not strings (which you _are_, in the example above), then none of this is necessary.  `000.1` _is_ `0.1` and `00005.5` _is_ `5.5`.

Comment: @marekful With `should`, I meant `my aim is`.

Comment: I see. What made you think ltrim() will ever leave the last occurrence of a character it's instructed to remove?

Comment: @marekful [...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098688/how-to-remove-all-leading-zeroes-in-a-string)

Comment: Difference is that in the link they wanted to remove all the leading zeros, you want to remove all but one.

Comment: That make me think that preg_replace will work too. Not that I recommend regex for such a simple solution. But it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply it with 1 and php will cast it to float.

```
echo "000.1"*1 . "\n";  //0.1
echo "0"*1 . "\n";      //0 
echo "00005.5"*1 . "\n";//5.5
```

https://3v4l.org/mnN56

Or float cast it

```
echo (float)"000.1" . "\n";
echo (float)"0" . "\n";
echo (float)"00005.5" . "\n";
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there any scenario where this would not work?

Comment: Not that I know. Possibly if you actuall input a string like "hello world".

Comment: Ah, I think float casting it sounds like the more readable approach. Thanks!

Comment: Doing a `+0` also works, and for ints. But there you can do `(int)"002"` as well... so I guess its more of a personal preference.