# Remove starting ZERO's from the string

Tags: php, split, substring

I have a string like this:

```
0000000020100

$string = "0000000020100";
$new_string = '';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string) ; $i++){
   if($string[$i] != '0'){
      $new_string .= $string[$i];
   }
}
echo $new_string;
```

but output I am getting as 21, I should get the output as 20100.

Comment: Well you’d have to _stop_ “skipping” any zeroes, that come after the first _non-zero_ digit …

Comment: You are appending any char that is not 0 for the whole string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098688/how-to-remove-all-leading-zeroes-in-a-string

Comment: (`ltrim` could do this in one go, btw. So unless you are doing this for exercise purposes, and therefor explicitly in such a basic way, you might want to look into that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$string = "0000000020100";
echo ltrim($string, '0');
```

Just use the function `ltrim()` and will do the job.

But you have also some more simple and safe solutions:

```
$string = "0000000020100";
echo (int)$string; // For the integer number

echo '<br>';

echo (float)$string; // For the float number
```

On the both cases you will get what you want and in the proper format.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Works For Only Starting Zeroes :

$string = "0000000020100";
$new_string = '';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string) ; $i++){
if($string[$i] == '0'){
 continue;
}
else{
 for($j=i;$j<strlen($string);$j++){
  $new_string .= $string[$j];
 }
}
break;
}
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: This is way too much code, especially considering `ltrim()` exists.